# Arrange data (comments) based on the most votes with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to arrange data (comments) based on which has the most votes using vue.js? Thanks.

```
data: {
    comments: [{
        title: "Great article!",
        votes: 5
    }, {
        title: "VueJs commenting system with votes!",
        votes: 5
    }, {
        title: "The random pun that gets a lot of upvotes",
        votes: 85
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please share what you have tried already and try to show samples of the data structures involved. I would suggest you take a look at the [How to Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to have better context for people trying to help and others having the same question. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 2):

You could check the Vue documentation itself, where your use case is properly described. See [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results).

Basically you have to:

1 - define a computed property performing the sorting, for example:

```
computed: {
    sortedComments: function () {
      return this.comments.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.votes) - parseInt(b.votes));
    }
}
```

2 - iterate over the computed property:

```
<li v-for="n in sortedComments">{{ n }}</li>
```